# Apache Spark : Reading file in Standalone cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am currently using a graph that i load from a file when i run my Graphx application locally.

I'd like to run the application in cluster standalone mode.

Do I have to make changes like place the file in each cluster node?
Can I leave my application unchanged and just keep the file in the driver?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow the executors on the node to access an input file, the file should be access by the nodes.

The preferred way is to read the file from a location which support multi nodes, e.g. *HDFS*, [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)

It is possible that placing a copy of the file on each node might work as well, but it isn't the recommended way.